# NaN values from OpenCV dft() C++

Tags: c++, opencv, nan, dft

Hiho,

I really cant figure out this one.

I am using opencv 2.4.2.

The dft()-function in the following example produces 
an image containing at least a single NaN value
for the last call of the compute()-function.

When altering anything in the code, 
even if it does not effect the dft,
then it suddenly works.

The code is just a minimal example of the problem 
and part of a huge project. Some part of the code dose not make 
any sense like this, but its just to show you the problem.

Now the question is "Am I doing something wrong?" 
I would expect the code to work like this.
I attached the images in case anyone wanna try himself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

const std::vector<float> compute(const cv::Mat& image)
{
    cv::Mat workingImage;
    cv::Mat imgDFT;
    cv::Mat img;

    cv::cvtColor(image, workingImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::resize(workingImage, img, cv::Size(256, 256));

    std::vector<float> result = std::vector<float>(1, 0);
    cv::copyMakeBorder(img, img, 32, 32, 32, 32, cv::BORDER_REFLECT);
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);

    cv::dft(img, imgDFT, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

    if (!cv::checkRange(imgDFT)) 
        std::cerr << "NaN in imgDFT" << std::endl;

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<float> descriptor0 = compute(cv::imread("1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR));
    std::vector<float> descriptor1 = compute(cv::imread("1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR));
    std::vector<float> descriptor2 = compute(cv::imread("2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR));
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcK44.jpg    (1.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBU8a.jpg    (2.jpg)

Comment: iirc you have to supply *float* images to dft()

Comment: I thought I do so by converting to CV_32FC1 :o

Comment: whaa, i'm blind, sorry .

Comment: It seems you should assign something to result, besides zero in initialization time.

Comment: @Andrey: I can't see how that would change the described behaviour. The result vector is in no way connected to the dft, so why should it affect its results?

Comment: Ok, I've not understand you question. And another thing you should try - dft for complex transform uses 2 channel float images. One channel for Re. , and one for Im. part. Input image should be the same as output. Try to add a zero channel to your input image.